# Javascript number in range condition not working

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var num = 67;
if(num >= 0 && num <= 100000) {
    console.log("This shouldn't run");
}
```

Theoretically this snippet of code should run, however when I run this JavaScript snippet it prints "This shouldn't run" to the console.

I have no idea why this isn't working, it's supposed to skip that code since `num` is between 0 and 100000.

Any idea what's up?

Comment: It works... what's the problem ?

Comment: Your number _is_ greater than 0 and less than 100000.

Comment: *It's supposed to skip that code since num is between 0 and 100000.* Not with that code, no.

Comment: @Alexis it's not working for me :/

Comment: `0 <= 67 <= 100000`, so...

Comment: Gosh I am drunk...  It's been a looooong day.  I see the issue, thanks.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle I wish I had posted my comment as an answer. It was true after all :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your condition literally checks whether `num` is greater or equal than zero and smaller or equal to `100000`. That's the case for `67`, so the conditional statement is executed.

If you want to **check whether `num` is *not* in the range, you could e.g. negate the condition**:

```
var num = 67;
if(!(num >= 0 && num <= 100000)) {
    console.log("This shouldn't run");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working entirely as expected.  Break down the if condition into separate parts if it's easier to see, i.e.

- Is num >= 0 : yes, 67 is greater than, or equal to, zero
- Is num <= 100000 : yes, 67 is less than or equal to 100,000

I think you meant your code to be...

```
var num = 67;
if(num <= 0 || num >= 100000) {
    console.log("This shouldn't run");
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what he meant, as this condition will never evaluate to true.

Answer (score -1):

The code is working fine.  The if statement executes correctly (the printed message is just confusing).

67 is greater than or equal to zero, and 67 is less than or equal to 100000, so the if statement's condition is true.  Since that is true, it will execute the block of statements that follow (i.e. the console.log).